# Partial Differential Equations Method of Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Obtain the solution to the initial value problem

$$u_t+u^2u_x=0\,,\,\,\,\,\,-\infty<x<\infty\,, \,\,\forall t>0 $$
$$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x<0\\x&\text{if}~0\leq x\end{cases}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem or can tell us where you are confused? It helps provide better guidance. Regards

Comment: In fact "solving first-order PDE with one condition" is just simply a game of first finding the general solution of the first-order PDE and then putting the condition to determine the arbitrary function. Don't think this too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=0$ , letting $u(0)=u_0$ , we have $u=u_0$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=u^2=u_0^2$ , letting $x(0)=f(u_0)$ , we have $x=u_0^2s+f(u_0)=u^2t+f(u)$ , i.e. $u=F(x-u^2t)$

$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x<0\\x&\text{if}~0\leq x\end{cases}=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x\leq0\\x&\text{if}~x\geq0\end{cases}=R(x)$ according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function#Definitions:

$F(x)=R(x)$

$\therefore u$

$=R(x-u^2t)$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x-u^2t\leq0\\x-u^2t&\text{if}~x-u^2t\geq0\end{cases}$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x-u^2t\leq0\\x&\text{if}~x-u^2t\geq0~\text{and}~t=0\\\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~x-u^2t\geq0~\text{and}~t\neq0\end{cases}$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x\leq0\\x&\text{if}~x\geq0~\text{and}~t=0\\\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}\geq0~\text{and}~t\neq0\\\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}\geq0~\text{and}~t\neq0\end{cases}$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x\leq0\\x&\text{if}~x\geq0~\text{and}~t=0\\\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~\left(\sqrt{4xt+1}\geq1~\text{and}~t>0\right)~\text{or}~\left(\sqrt{4xt+1}\leq1~\text{and}~t<0\right)\\\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~\left(\sqrt{4xt+1}\leq-1~\text{and}~t>0\right)~\text{or}~\left(\sqrt{4xt+1}\geq-1~\text{and}~t<0\right)\end{cases}$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x\leq0\\x&\text{if}~x\geq0~\text{and}~t=0\\\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~\left(4xt+1\geq1~\text{and}~t>0\right)~\text{or}~\left(0\leq4xt+1\leq1~\text{and}~t<0\right)\\\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~4xt+1\geq0~\text{and}~t<0\end{cases}$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x\leq0\\x&\text{if}~x\geq0~\text{and}~t=0\\\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~\left(xt\geq0~\text{and}~t>0\right)~\text{or}~\left(-\dfrac{1}{4}\leq xt\leq0~\text{and}~t<0\right)\\\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{4xt+1}}{2t}&\text{if}~xt\geq-\dfrac{1}{4}~\text{and}~t<0\end{cases}$